How does cloning a page directory work without breaking the stack?
I'm working on a process scheduler for my OS (it's been a rough journey) and I'm running into a big problem - for some reason, when I switch to my idle process' page directory (after switching to a different process, twice for some reason), it causes a page fault for the stack.
This is confusing to me because I'm pretty sure it's because my code is bugged, but I have absolutely zero idea how I should begin to fix this. It seems like expected behavior though, and that's what's getting me.
Here's how I see the situation:

Process 'idle' is created and given a stack and cloned a page directory from kernel page directory
Process 'thread' is allocated a stack and cloned a page directory from kernel page directory (which will just create a "snapshot" of the mappings there, not actually copy content of pages)
Switching starts, and 'thread' executes once and sleeps for 2 seconds.
In that time, 'idle' just idles around.
'thread' executes again, says hi and sleeps again.
The next time switching happens after thread sleeps, loading the PDBR for 'idle' causes a page fault (unrecoverable in QEMU so it reboots).

I looked at QEMU logs, and here is the exception:
4605: v=0e e=0000 i=0 cpl=0 IP=0008:001277b7 pc=001277b7 SP=0010:005acf6c CR2=005acf6c

If it means anything, my process stack allocation is pretty bad and relies on using sbrk() in the kernel and just remapping it to usermode. This is terrible and I would normally blame that but it should work, especially because my scheduler impl. is based off of another project
Here is the basic code that sets up a stack and page directory:
// Setup the image stack
// This is DEFINITELY unsafe.
proc->image.stack = (uintptr_t)mem_sbrk(KSTACK_SIZE) + KSTACK_SIZE;
for (uint32_t i = 0; i < KSTACK_SIZE; i += 0x1000) {
    pte_t *page = mem_getPage(NULL, (proc->image.stack - KSTACK_SIZE) + i, MEM_CREATE);
    mem_allocatePage(page, MEM_DEFAULT);
}

// Setup page directory
proc->thread.page_directory = cloneDirectory(mem_getKernelDirectory());

Any help or ideas would be appreciated. Thanks!
